# Is there a way to use a Visual Studio 2019 install after reinstalling Windows?

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, visual-studio-2019

I'm currently trying to use my Visual Studio 2019 installation that I installed on a previous installation of Windows. I've reinstalled Windows a couple of weeks ago, and it is now detected as "Pre-release software" and will not re-activate.

There is a server error when trying to check for a license, and I do not want to reinstall unless absolutely necessary. Is there any way to fix this? I have already tried to reset Settings, and it won't re-activate. I've tried looking online and I can't find anything else about this issue. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you won't be able to just copy your program files from a prior install for visual studio. its installation creates many registry entries, and it installs a lot of dependencies on the system  outside of its program files directory.  Sorry. Visual studio is a large complex package, with rather deep integration into the OS.